# Dismissing picker from MVVMCross DateElement

Tags: mvvmcross, monotouch.dialog

I am using the DateElement in MVVMCross that was forked from Monotouch Dialog.

I can get the DatePicker to appear when I touch the DateElement, the problem is I cannot see how to dismiss the PickerView once I have selected the Date.

Comment: Can you post some example code?

Comment: I've decided to implement my own Date Control now but will try and knock something up. I suspect the issue is related to how I am using MT D. I have crating a RootElement myself, adding it to a DVC and then adding that to the View of an MvxViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was completely to do with the way we use MT D, moving the DialogViewController's View into a View one level higher than expected. See my answer to this question, [Back Button missing from nested Monotouch Dialog RootElement Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504259/back-button-missing-from-nested-monotouch-dialog-rootelement-views/31915870#31915870)